# Scovolino, significato, WC

Tags: single-words

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere perché il dizionario Treccani non lista "scovolino", come parola usata per indicare la spazzola a estremità tondeggiante con manico di ferro usata per pulire il water.

Grazie.

Comment: @DaG a volte viene usato (impropriamente) scovolo per lo scopino - es. (https://www.gottardospazzole.it/prodotti/scope-e-spazzole-per-la-casa/spazzole-per-il-bagno/scovolo-wc/)(https://www.gottardospazzole.it/prodotti/scope-e-spazzole-per-la-casa/spazzole-per-il-bagno/scovolo-wc/) e (https://www.arix.it/prodotti/casa/tonkita-scovolo-wc/)(https://www.arix.it/prodotti/casa/tonkita-scovolo-wc/), scovolino potrebbe esserne un diminutivo usato regionalmente.

Comment: In ogni caso, come @BakerStreet, si tratterebbe di usi locali.

Comment: Grazie per i link, ma mi sembra che non si usi “scovolino” (per quello del wc), ma solo “scovolo”. So che sembra una pignoleria, ma ci sono molti casi in cui un diminutivo cambia significato e si riferisce a un oggetto diverso: vetro/vetrino, formaggio/formaggino, pipa/pipetta, martello/martelletto etc.

Comment: Emendo un mio precedente commento: voto per chiudere questa domanda perché è priva di senso: 1) è della forma “perché X?”, quando invece X (cioè che la parola “scovolino” si usi in quel senso) è tutto da dimostrare; 2) se anche X fosse vero, bisognerebbe chiedere alla Treccani perché include o meno certe voci.

Comment: Ma, come dice Treccani, *scovolino si usa* , vedi https://www.leroymerlin.it/prodotti/bagno-e-arredo-bagno/accessori-bagno-appoggio/porta-scopino/scovolino-bagno-p.html oppure https://www.trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_arredo-bagno_scovolino_da_wc.aspx . Da non perdere https://regalol.it/idee-regalo/casa/bagno/scovolino-wc-microfono/

Comment: Forse mi sono spiegato male, @BakerStreet: certo che “scovolino” è registrato sul Treccani, ma in altri significati, come lo stesso OP riscontra. Nel mio commento precedente parlavo solo dei link postati da d1nuc0m. Nei link che segnali tu (a parte quello del microfono... :) ) è curioso che nel titolo venga menzionato lo “scovolino”, ma poi i singoli articoli si chiamano “scopino” o “spazzolino”.

Comment: Ci sta anche nel testo del secondo link, uno dei primi articoli. Ma è la prima ricerca di due minuti che ho fatto, ce ne saranno di sicuro altri. Nei testi c'è 'scopino', credo perché è il termine più standard, e quello usano per lo più i venditori, ma nelle ricerche su google c'è 'scovolino' perché parecchie persone lo chiameranno così e lo cercheranno così. Nel Treccani poi parla di 'scovolino' regionale per 'scopetta', 'scopettina', non vedo questa grande differenza tra 'scopettina' e 'scopettino'.

Comment: Comunque, io, di tutti questi termini, apprezzo di più la parola separata "scovolino". Anche, per motivi, di poter tenere un minimo di pulizia, in bagno, e in casa (non confondendo un oggetto con l'altro).

Answer (score 4):

Per la verità il dizionario Treccani riporta il significato di *scovolino* come *scopetta, scopettina*, di uso regionale.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scovolino/,

Per la verità io non ho mai sentito questo termine usato nel senso che dici tu, per la pulizia del water, ma appunto, si tratta di usi regionali.

Questi nomi di cose quotidiane sono molto soggetti a varianti regionali e locali.

Comment: Condivido: @Joselin, ci puoi segnalare qualche contesto in cui “scovolino” viene usato con il significato che dici?

Comment: Beh, l'ho sentito nel linguaggio parlato. Ma, se questa non è la parola giusta per quell'oggetto, allora non so quale lo sia.

Comment: Forse mi puoi indicare qualche parola. Grazie.

Comment: Non è la che non è parola giusta, dipende dalle abitudini locali, se da te usano 'scovolino' (termine regionale) usalo anche tu, se vuoi. Vedo usato per lo più, su internet,  'scopino', io per la verità dove ho vissuto ho sentito sempre 'scopettino', e uso quello. Insomma, usa quello che ti pare, va bene comunque, o quello che non suona 'strano' nel posto in cui vivi.